# Facebook login MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

**I have to do a  log in button in MVC, i searched for alot of tutorials on how to do and i found one i think is good but everytime i run de program i keep getting an exception**

```
`public ActionResult FacebookCallBack(string code)
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/acces_token", new
            {
                client_id = "",
                client_secret = "",
                redirect_uri = RedirectedUri.AbsoluteUri,
                code = code
            });
            var accesToken = result.acces_token;
            Session["AccesToken"] = accesToken;
            fb.AccessToken = accesToken;
            dynamic me = fb.Get("me?field=link,first_name,currency,last_name,email,gender,locale,timezone,verified,picture,age_range");
            string email = me.email;
            string lastname = me.last_name;
            string picture = me.picture.data.url;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
`
```

this is the exception 
Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: '(OAuthException - #1) client_secret should not be passed to /oauth/acces_token'

also this is the Facebook Action

```
public ActionResult Facebook()
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
            {
                client_id = "",
                client_secret = "",
                redirect_uri = RedirectedUri.AbsoluteUri,
                response_type = "code",
                scope = "email"
            });
            return Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: Exchanging the code for a token happens via a _GET_ request to `oauth/acces_token`, not a POST.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Do you use the Identity Framework for authentication? It comes with a built-in configuration which allows you to easily configure authentication with external providers, such as Facebook.